# OpenShift 3: How To Access POSTGRESQL POD Environment Variables Using Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, environment-variables, openshift

I have a Java webapp running successfully on Tomcat.

I have created three environment variables in my **myapp** deployment:

```
MY_ENV_VAR_1=dbuser
MY_ENV_VAR_2=dbpassword
MY_ENV_VAR_3=dbname
```

I can get these values using standard Java code:

> ```
> myEnvVar1 = System.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR_1");
> myEnvVar2 = System.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR_2");
> myEnvVar3 = System.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR_3");
> ```

I used 'normal Java' code to connect to the database:

> connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + postgresqlServiceHost + ":" + postgresqlServicePort + "/" + myEnvVar3, myEnvVar1, myEnvVar2);

**So, I can connect to the database successfully.**

The problem is:

I can see (in web console) but cannot get the values from the three environment variables in the postgresql deployment:

```
POSTGRESQL_USER
POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD
POSTGRESQL_DATABASE
```

Using the 'normal' System.getenv("POSTGRESQL_USER"); does NOT work.

**So, please can someone tell me how to access the values of these three postgresql pod environment variables using Java Code?**

Comment: Did you add them to the deployment configuration for your application? They are not added automatically when you deploy the database. See example for adding database environment variables to application in https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html

Comment: Thanks Graham, I actually found your book earlier and saw that env vars are not initially added to the app. So I added them manually and it started to work. Is this the correct way to do it? For future reference...

Comment: For now it is. Down the track when the Open Service Broker is properly incorporated in OpenShift, when linking a database to an application there will be a way of having the environment variables be automatically populated. I don't know when they may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the simple answer is:

You manually add the following three environment variables to the deployment environment of the application that will be accessing the database.

```
POSTGRESQL_USER
POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD
POSTGRESQL_DATABASE
```

You must do it in exactly the same way as you see them in the postgresql deployment environment.

It really is that simple...

In Java app:

```
String postgresqlServiceHost = System.getenv("POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_HOST");
String postgresqlServicePort = System.getenv("POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_PORT");
String postgresqlDatabase = System.getenv("POSTGRESQL_DATABASE");
String postgresqlUser = System.getenv("POSTGRESQL_USER");
String postgresqlPassword = System.getenv("POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD");

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + postgresqlServiceHost + ":" + postgresqlServicePort + "/" + postgresqlDatabase, postgresqlUser, postgresqlPassword);
```